# Grails 2.0.4 and sql profiling using p6spy plug-in configuration

Tags: sql, grails, profiling, p6spy

I am using grails 2.0.4.  Even though the sql profiler client is connecting; p6spy is not logging anything.

I suspect that the problem lies in the property file, or that there is a conflict with my 
Config.groovy log4j settings.

**• spy.properties**

```
module.log=com.p6spy.engine.logging.P6LogFactory

realdriver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

dateformat=HH:mm:ss

deregisterdrivers=false

executionthreshold=

outagedetection=false

outagedetectioninterval=

filter=false

include  =

exclude  =

sqlexpression =

autoflush= true

includecategories=

excludecategories=

stringmatcher=

stacktrace=false

stacktraceclass=

reloadproperties=false

reloadpropertiesinterval=60

useprefix=false

appender=com.p6spy.engine.logging.appender.Log4jLogger

append=true

log4j.appender.SQLPROFILER_CLIENT=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender

log4j.appender.SQLPROFILER_CLIENT.RemoteHost=localhost

log4j.appender.SQLPROFILER_CLIENT.Port=4445

log4j.appender.SQLPROFILER_CLIENT.LocationInfo=true

log4j.logger.p6spy=DEBUG,SQLPROFILER_CLIENT
```

**• DataSource.groovy**

```
dataSource {

    pooled = true

    logSql = true

    //driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

    driverClassName = "com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver" // use this driver to enable p6spy logging

    dialect = 'org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect'

}
```

**• Config.Groovy**

```
// log4j configuration

log4j = {

    appenders {

        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{ISO8601} [%c{1}] %p: %m%n')

    }

    info    'grails.app' // Logging warnings and higher for all of the app

    error   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    trace    'org.hibernate.type'

}
```

Comment: If you just want to see the SQL hibernate is generating, a simpler alternative to p6spy is to set the log level for `org.hibernate.SQL` to `DEBUG` in `Config.groovy`.

Comment: Thanks Taylor for your response, my goal is to verify my ehcache strategy is enhancing the performance.  I am receiving thousands of calls a minute.

Comment: Have you managed to get this working somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of this problem is that the Oracle JDBC driver is being registered by DriverManager before P6SpyDriver.  P6Spy 1.3 requires that P6SpyDriver gets registered before the real driver.  This is what allowed it to work without any modifications to the JDBC URL.

There are two potential solutions to this issue.

1) Set 'deregisterdrivers=false' in spy.properties.  This will cause the driver configured as the 'realdriver' in spy.properties to be deregistered and reregistered when P6SpyDriver is loaded.  This enforces the correct ordering within DriverManager.

2) Set 'useprefix=true' in spy.properties and add the prefix 'p6spy:' to your JDBC URL.  Since the JDBC URL is different, the order of registration no longer matters.

Further troubleshooting tips: http://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/1.3/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with P6Spy not detecting the right driver for H2. In the end I went with [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/). It has more recent updates to its code. P6Spy hasn't been updated in quite sometime, but maybe there has been no need to. I scribbled a few lines in my blog on my experience of [log4jdbc, grails and tomcat7](http://www.34m0.com/2012/11/log4jdbcgrailstomcat7.html). It might be of some use to you!